# What metric should I use to compare two feature vectors of two images?

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, similarity, feature-extraction, cosine-similarity

I am looking for a way to compare the feature vectors of two images that contain a person in it. The application should be able to output a high similarity score for the same person and a lower score if the people in the photos are different. What I have tried so far: I have extracted two feature vectors using the VGG19 pretrained network. I gave as an input a picture of myself and the same picture but mirrored. I have tried using cosine similarity between these two feature vectors but it gives me a score of only 0.3 similarity. I have tried changing the layer from which I extract the activation map (after each max pool layer) but I can get only 0.5 for the same person but mirrored. It would even give me a higher score for different persons than for the picture with myself compared to the same picture but mirrored. Here you can see an example of an output after the block3_pool/MaxPool layer for both pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVszK.jpg. What other metric I could use? I have also tried using Euclidean distance but works even worse than cosine. It gives me a bigger distance between the photos with myself than between photos of other people.

Thank you!

Comment: You could train a network to decide.

Comment: What kind of network? I don't want this to be supervised. I want it to be able to tell the difference or similarity of two body silhouettes in two photos.

Comment: If you do not want this to be supervised you need to think of a metric, (e.g. a mathematical function) that describes the similarity of two bodyshapes in images, yourself. And that for sure is non trivial. I highly doubt someone will post some magic piece of code or math here for you.